# Magento2: How to set limit display product in block

Tags: magento2

I have block "product on sale".

```
<div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="panel-block-row col-md-12">{{block class="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Products\Saleoff" mgs_panel_title="" mgs_panel_note="" limit="40" ratio="4" category_ids="" use_slider="0" loadmore="0" template="products/saleoff.phtml" perrow="4"}}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

only that it displays all products from the store that are on sale. I would like to limit and display only  eg. 100 products on sale.

Answer (score 1):

Check on that block : MGS\Mpanel\Block\Products\Saleoff

There should be a function which load collection of products so do like as i did change on that collection.

```
public function getProducts() {
        $collection = $this->_collection
                           ->addMinimalPrice()
                           ->addFinalPrice()
                           ->addTaxPercents()
                           ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                           ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', 1, 'left');
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(100);
        return $collection;
    }
```

so add this code like as i did add above.

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(100);
```